# Prevent editing cells in excel files generated by Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I would like to generate excel files using Apache POI but I don't want the viewers of the files to edit the files. I also would like to allow them to copy and paste the contents but I don't want them to edit these contents in the new files either. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cell style to do this. setLocked() helps you achieve this.

```
CellStyle unlockedCellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();// wb-> workbook
unlockedCellStyle.setLocked(true); //you need to set it based on your //requirements
cell.setCellStyle(unlockedCellStyle); //cell-> the cell you need to lock
```

Answer (score 0):

Just protect the sheet by using this code, you can also give password to enable editing.

sheet.protectSheet("password");